# Grouping and checking for a condition in R

Tags: r

I have two tables: `restaurant_trans` and `restaurant_master`

`restaurant_trans` has name, date, net_sales

This is a transaction file with sales for 50 restaurant recorded for 30 days each (1500 obs).

`restaurant_master` has name, go.live.date, franchise

This is a master file with name of the restaurant and 'go.live.date' is the date a particular device was installed in the restaurant.

I want to find the net sales of the restaurant before and after the device was installed. I first want the data to be grouped.

I tried this code for subsetting the data

```
dummayvar = 0;

for (i in 1:nrow(restaurant_master)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(restaurant_trans)){
    if(restaurant_trans$Restaurant.Name[j]==restaurant_master$Restaurant.Name[i]){
      if(restaurant_trans$Date[j] < restaurant_master$Go.Live.Date[i]){
      append(dummayvar, restaurant_trans$Date)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving an error :

> "level sets of factors are different"

Please help!!

Comment: How did you define tables?

Comment: Didn't you miss index (i or j) in append?

Comment: Set `i` and `j` to some values; test each condition to see if it runs... at least  then you'll know what line is giving the error. Probably it's your Restaurant.Name line. If so, just quit using factors and you're golden.

Comment: Why are you writing a nested loop instead of a join?

Comment: Like Frank suggested, the variables were factors and hence the error. I converted them to characters. Loop seems to be running now but it's taking a lot of time to load. Any other better alternatives?

Comment: Frank, it's better to start using RStudio step-by-step debugging ))

Comment: @Dmitriy Yes, maybe so. I don't use RStudio, but also don't find that I need to debug very often. By the way @ before a name will ping a person so they see your chat message.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [merge()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/merge) instead of nested `for` loops. Simply merge restaurant `netsales` and `master` data frames by name and then subset data frames according to net sales' dates and master's go.live.dates. Finally, aggregate net sales by restaurant name and franchise or individually.

```
# DATA FRAME EXAMPLES
netsales <- data.frame(name=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                              'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                              'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
              date=c('6/1/2015', '6/15/2015', '7/1/2015', '9/1/2015', '11/15/2015', 
                     '6/5/2015', '6/20/2015', '7/15/2015', '8/1/2015', '10/15/2015',
                     '6/10/2015', '7/10/2015', '8/15/2015', '9/20/2015', '9/30/2015'),
              net_sales=c(1500,  600,  1200,  850,  750,  
                          1120,  560,  720,  340,  890,  
                          1150,  410,  300,  250,  900))    
netsales$date <- as.Date(strptime(netsales$date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
str(netsales)    

master <- data.frame(name=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                     go.live.date=c('7/25/2015', '8/1/2015', '7/1/2015'),
                     franchise=c('R Co.', 'Python, Inc.', 'C# Ltd.'))

master$go.live.date <- as.Date(strptime(master$go.live.date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
str(master)    

# MERGE AND AGGREGATE BEFORE GO LIVE SALES
beforelive <- merge(netsales, master, by='name')
beforelive <- beforelive[beforelive$date < beforelive$go.live.date,]

beforelivesales <- aggregate(net_sales ~ name + franchise, beforelive, FUN=sum)

# MERGE AND AGGREGATE AFTER GO LIVE SALES
afterlive <- merge(netsales, master, by='name')
afterlive <- afterlive[afterlive$date >= afterlive$go.live.date,]

afterlivesales <- aggregate(net_sales ~ name + franchise, afterlive, FUN=sum)
```